# Use a summary field in an expression in SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services, sum, expression, summary, ssrs-expression

I have the details of my report being summed up in a summary expression, all works fine.  The fields are decimal values of hours worked.  Thus, the summary value is also a decimal value.  I'd like to access the summary value and convert it to hours / minutes.  I've labeled the express as "WorkTimeSum", but can't seem to get a handle to it, however.  Fields! obviously won't work since it is a summary expression.  I was thinking ReportItems! should work, but to no avail.  How can I use this expression field (in a summary row) in an expression in the same summary row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, you're asking how to reference the textbox containing the total work hours value so that you can convert it to hours and minutes using an expression in a different textbox?

You can use either ReportItems! e.g.

```
=ReportItems!Textbox20.Value)
```

or ReportItems("") e.g.

```
=ReportItems("Textbox20").Value
```

to reference the value of another textbox. Be careful with the names as they are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate functions in any expression. For example, in any header rows you can use the following expression to determine the total hours value:

```
=Floor(Sum(Fields!hours.Value))
```

`Sum(Fields!hours.Value)` is just the total hours in whatever context, e.g. the group total if it's a group header row; you can use this expression as an input in any other expression you require.

It sounds like your issue wasn't the conversion itself, so hopefully this points you in the right direction. If you need further information please specify.